# How to access value from json issue in android

Tags: android, json

I am trying to access value of 'cod' from the json string :

```
 {"coord":{"lon":73.86,"lat":18.52},"sys":{"message":0.0293,"country":"IN","sunrise":1428972502,"sunset":1429017681},"weather":[{"id":801,"main":"Clouds","description":"few clouds","icon":"02d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":304.301,"temp_min":304.301,"temp_max":304.301,"pressure":951.61,"sea_level":1021.56,"grnd_level":951.61,"humidity":36},"wind":{"speed":2.06,"deg":302.501},
        "clouds":{"all":24},"dt":1428996633,"id":1259229,"name":"Pune","cod":200}
```

But I am not able to get this value from my code. the code I am using to access this value from json string is as:

```
  try{
                   JSONObject jsObject=(new JSONObject(JsonString)).getJSONObject("coord");

                    if(  jsObject.getInt("cod")==200) {

                        i.putExtra("jsn", JsonString);
                        i.putExtra("city", etCity.getText().toString());
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the if condition, you are trying to access the key `"cod"` in the array `{"lon":73.86,"lat":18.52}`. It will throw a `JSONException`.

Try this :

```
try{
    JSONObject jsonmain = new JSONOBject(JsonString);
    if(jsonmain.getInt("cod") == 200) {
        i.putExtra("jsn", JsonString);
        i.putExtra("city", etCity.getText().toString());
        startActivity(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your json is:

```
{
"coord": {
    "lon": 73.86,
    "lat": 18.52
},
"sys": {
    "message": 0.0293,
    "country": "IN",
    "sunrise": 1428972502,
    "sunset": 1429017681
},
"weather": [
    {
        "id": 801,
        "main": "Clouds",
        "description": "few clouds",
        "icon": "02d"
    }
],
"base": "stations",
"main": {
    "temp": 304.301,
    "temp_min": 304.301,
    "temp_max": 304.301,
    "pressure": 951.61,
    "sea_level": 1021.56,
    "grnd_level": 951.61,
    "humidity": 36
},
"wind": {
    "speed": 2.06,
    "deg": 302.501
},
"clouds": {
    "all": 24
},
"dt": 1428996633,
"id": 1259229,
"name": "Pune",
"cod": 200
}
```

The key "cod" is not nested inside "coord".

Try: 
    `new JSONObject(JsonString)).getInt("cod");`

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are trying wrong JSON Object.

```
  String cod=(new JSONObject(JsonString)).getJSONObject("code").toString();
                 //you may need to try catch block
                if(  Integer.parseint(cod)==200) {

                   .... Your logic
                }
```